# Facebook message sending failed using xmpp in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, xmpp, xmppframework

I am using this code to send a message but my message is not delivered.
Whereas I receive messages sent from facebook.
Please help me as I don't know what i am doing wrong.

```
if([textMessage length] > 0){
    NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
    [body setStringValue:textMessage];
    NSXMLElement *message = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"xmlns" stringValue:@"http://www.facebook.com/xmpp/messages"];
    [message addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"-%@@chat.facebook.com",friendID]];
    [message addChild:body];
    [self.xmppStream sendElement:message];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody else was having the same problem, the "xmlns" attribute had to be changed from the Facebook url to "jabber:client" in order to work.